# Pygame Rect not appearing on display

Tags: python, pygame

I know this must have been answered a number of times, but unfortunately, the topic is difficult to search and I am truly at a los, as Python is not throwing an error.

I am following a Python Crash Course tutorial (Eric Matthes) and am programming a game along the lines of space invaders. The below Module is intended to control the bullets:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
"""A class to manage bullets fired from the ship"""

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """Create bullet at the ships current positio"""
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = screen

    # Create a bullet rect at (0, 0) and then set the correct position.
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, 
        ai_settings.bullet_height)
    self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
    self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

    # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value.
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
    self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

def update(self):
    """Move the bullet up the screen."""
    # Update the decimal position of the bullet.
    self.y -= self.speed_factor
    # Update the rect position.
    self.rect.y = self.y

def draw_bullet(self):
    """Draw the bullet on the screen."""
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

The actual game screen is printing the bullet count, so I know the bullets are on the screen and also vanish again, as the move towards the edge of the screen, but they are not displayed.

The game itself looks as follows:

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)

    # Make a group to store the bullets in.
    bullets = Group()

    # Start main loop for the game

   while True:
   #Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
       gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
       ship.update()
       gf.update_bullets(bullets) 



       gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

       # Redraw Screen during each pass through.
       screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
       ship.blitme()

       # Make most recently drawn visible
       pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

The settings are there and no, the bullets are not the same color as the screen;-)

Can anyone help me find my error in thinking?
My impression is, the pygame.draw.rect function should make them display in combination with the gf.update_bullets(bullets) call.

Many thanks and best regards,
Simon

Additional File added:
game_functions.py

```
import sys

import pygame
from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        # Move the ship to the right.
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    # Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group.
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to keypresses"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        # Move the ship to the right.
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):

    # Redraw all bullets behind the ship and aliens
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()

def update_bullets(bullets):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets"""
    # Update bullet position
    bullets.update()

    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
    print(len(bullets))



    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
```

Comment: I can't see any call to the draw_bullet() method.  Is that done in ship.blitme()?

Comment: Hi Alkanen, many thanks for your quick feedback.
this is actually in another "game_functions" file - uploading here as well:

Comment: I see @sloth gave you the answer I was fishing for.  I didn't see your draw, so I wasn't sure you actually performed a draw in update_screen() or if that only moved things on the screen to be drawn later =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the order in which you draw things to the screen surface.

You call `gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)`, and after that, you actually erase the whole screen with `screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)`.

Make sure to call `screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)` first, *then* draw your other stuff.

---

There are some other issues with your code, e.g.

- you use the Sprite class, but your sprites don't have an `image` attribute, which makes using Sprite kind of pointless
- you already use the Group class for your sprites, but draw them manually with a `for` loop and the `draw_bullet` function. Just give your bullets an `image` and call `bullets.draw(screen)` instead
- you check if bullets are outside the screen in `update_bullets`. The the bullet class handle it itself, by simply using something like this:

  `if not self.screen.rect.contains(self.rect):
      self.kill`
- your entire game_functions.py file makes your code hard to read

Comment: Many thanks Sloth, the order of screen.fill and gf.update_screen did the trick. I also appreciate the comment - as it's a tutorial I guess I need to stick to the book for the moment, but I'll try that out once it's all working. Many thanks here.